# aspnetdb Adding Roles and Users

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

In VS2013 They taken the Website Administration Tool that you used to be able to set up Roles and membership.  I'm trying to add an "Admin" role to my site and add my user name to it but everything I've tried has not worked.

var roleManager = new RoleManager(new RoleStore(context));
    roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Administrator"));

```
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin" };
userManager.Create(user, "admin321");
userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Administrator");
```

Running this in my MVC5 web app. gives me the following error;

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context.

the error is produced on the;
roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Administrator"));

Comment: Sounds like you need to override the Identity setup to use your custom IdentityRole class. Anyways, they took away the Website Administration Tool, but [Thinktecture.IdentityManager](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager) fulfills that role, and I believe is a project sponsored by the .NET Foundation. Might be worth looking into it. Here's a [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThinktectureIdentityManagerAsAReplacementForTheASPNETWebSiteAdministrationTool.aspx) about it by a Microsoft employee.

Comment: Nice utility but doesn't work with roles yet only users.

Comment: It does work with roles. Keep in mind, that blog post was written nearly a year ago. Obviously the software hasn't stood still for a year!

Comment: It won't built for me during build nuGet is trying to update the solution and returns;

1>G:\Downloads\IdentityManager-master\source\.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error MSB3073: The command ""G:\Downloads\IdentityManager-master\source\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "G:\Downloads\IdentityManager-master\source\Host\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "G:\Downloads\IdentityManager-master\source\ "" exited with code 1.

Comment: You're trying to run IdentityManager from source? While you can do that I'm sure, I'd rather just use NuGet to add it to my app. They have [a package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityManager) for you.

Comment: I added that package before the build twice just to make sure I had done it.  That;s why I don't understand why it's trying to update??

Comment: Looks like you did *something* with the source. I don't know, hard to say. If it's something you really want to get working, you should probably make a separate question for it.

Comment: Whew found it, after nearly driving me back to drink, I knew it was simple but google has not been kind.  See answer

Comment: mason thanks for all your help I really appreciate it and if I had enough rep points would give you an attaboy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer here; [ASP.Net MVC 4.5 Owin Simple Role Management by Anders G. Nordby](https://andersnordby.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/asp-net-mvc-4-5-owin-simple-roles-management/)

And here is the key code to create an Admin account and assign a user;

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

        roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));

        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

        var user = userManager.FindByEmail("my.email@somewhere.com");
        userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```